# Admin-ajax.php 500 error when Add to menu is clicked in admin

Tags: menus, admin, server

In the WordPress(V 4.9.9) admin panel when I click the "Add menu item", the never ending spinning wheel starts and I get the admin-ajax.php 500 error in the console. The error is something as below

POST https://somedomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500

I tried increasing the define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' ); in web-config.php

and max_input_vars = 6000 ; in php.ini but it did not resolve the issue.

And there nor error regarding this issue in error.log and debug.log. I even contacted the server support and he mentioned there nothing the server log as well.

Bit frustrated now as I'm able to perform the same action on my localhost without any problem but on the live server I throw the error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A 500 error is just Nginx/Apache telling you: " something went wrong in PHP, don't know what it was, check the PHP error logs". A bit like asking someone if something worked and them responding with "shrug", you need to look at the PHP error log to get the real error message. Until you do that, all we know is that something went wrong, and we have no idea what that is. If you don't know where that is, your host should be able to help, or help with turning error reporting on if it's turned off ( are you sure you checked the PHP log and not the Apache/Nginx log? )

Answer (score 2):

If you have problem with:

**POST wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 in WP**

`define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );` in wp-config.php

`max_input_vars = 6000 ;` in php.ini

and deactivate all plugins and active one by one until you see which plugin is causing problem.

(Ps. have the great chance to be the Yoast SEO plugin the problem)

Answer (score 1):

Finally,  it turned out that it was Sucuri plugin that was causing the WordPress Ajax issue. I deactivate the plugin, cleared the  cache and active it the plugin again  after performing the desired admin task.